# knitr: R output in same chunk

Tags: r, knitr

When knitting an Rmd to an md document, is there an option to put the R output in the same chunk as the code?

````
> knit.txt = 'Hello
+ ```{r}
+ 3+3
+ a <- 3+3
+ ```'

> library(knitr)

> out = knit(text=knit.txt, quiet=TRUE)

> cat(out)
Hello

```r
3+3
```

```
## [1] 6
```

```r
a <- 3+3
```
````

You can see knitr produces three chunks but intead I want one chunk look  like this:

```
3+3
##6
a <- 3+3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the chunk option `collapse = TRUE`

````
```{r, collapse = TRUE}
3+3
a <- 3 + 3
```
````

Comment: That's goint in the right way, but I have a a bunch of Rmd files I want to knit and it would be nice if editing them is circumventable.

Comment: Found it: Simply set `opts_chunk$set(collapse=TRUE)` before calling 'knitr'